# How to show login/logout links the rails way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a property that is exposed in my view @is_logged_in

if its true, then I want to show the 'logout' link, otherwise I want to show the 'login' link.

Is there a fancy rails way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
<% if @is_logged_in %>
  <%= link_to("Logout", logout_path) %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to("Login", login_path) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= link_to_if(@is_logged_in, "Logout", logout_path) do
       link_to("Login", login_path)
    end
%>
```